# mongoose fail to save a large document, RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "offset" is out of range

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I´m having trouble at saving a large document with mongoose / nodejs client. I´m creating a data model from retreiving data from my mySQL database and storing it to a document.

So far i haven´t had any trouble, but now i´m getting this error:

```
RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 && <= 17825792. Received 17825799
    at validateOffset (node:buffer:117:3)
    at Buffer.write (node:buffer:1076:5)
    at serializeObject (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\eda_api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:342:14)
    at serializeInto (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\eda_api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:947:17)
    at serializeObject (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\eda_api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\eda_api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:729:17)
    at serializeObject (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\eda_api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\eda_api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:947:17)
    at serializeObject (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\eda_api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\eda_api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:729:17)
    at serializeObject (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\eda_api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\eda_api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:947:17)
    at serializeObject (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\eda_api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\eda_api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:947:17)
    at serializeObject (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\eda_api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\eda_api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:947:17) {
  code: 'ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE'
}
```

I believe it is because the document is too large, but i haven´t found a proper way to split it into parts or anything similar. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

I haven´t tried much yet, any suggestion will be very helpful.
I tried with GridFS, but it doesn´t seem to be the solution.

Comment: MongoDB does have a limit of 16MB per document, is your document larger than that?

Comment: That´s what it seems... It´s actually not much larger, it states: It must be >= 0 && <= 17825792. Received 17825799.